# PowerBI Athena Beta Connector Details: "We cannot convert the value null to type Record."

Tags: amazon-web-services, powerbi, odbc, amazon-athena, powerbi-desktop

I am trying to connect to AWS Athena from Power BI using the new Athena connector. The first page prompts for a DSN which I supply (and which works when connecting through the old ODBC method) but when the new connector attempts to connect with this DSN the following error is thrown:

> Unable to connect
>
> We encountered an error while trying to connect.  Details: "We cannot
> convert the value null to type Record."

Comment: I am stuck with same issue. I hope someone answers this soon.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue and I figured out the reason it was happening. When you mention your *DSN* in the *Amazon Athena (Beta)*, the next thing it will ask is your login (which has two options).**Do not take the 2nd option**. Pick the first option where the all setting are pulled from your DSN settings, which you did to setup your datasource.

Now if you once did it wrong, It won't ask you again the same things to fix it. Create a new powerbi file and do the steps.

Comment: Additional input regarding "Now if you once did it wrong, It won't ask you again the same things to fix it. Create a new powerbi file and do the steps." - you do not need to create new Power BI file, simply go to your data source settings and edit permissions

Answer (score 1):

As Janzaib mentioned above, you picked the wrong option when you set up your datasource. But you don't need to create a new file. You can click **Data source settings** and then find the name of the DSN and edit the permissions. Then the setting is pulled from your DSN and you are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do a strange workaround to get this to work for me. When I selected the Amazon Athena connection type in PowerBI, typed in the DSN name, and hit OK, I got the error above with no way to correct it. To get it to work, I typed a dummy name in the Role entry ("xyz") before hitting OK. Then I was presented with an authentication dialog - where I could select "Use Data Source Configuration," which would work.